# AndroidStudio - Binding Service in Fragment

Tags: java, android, service, binding, fragment

I want to use BindingService, and I'm making a simple game code
if I get answer, I can get correctcount+1.
Also I want to show this correctcount to result, so I used Binding Service.
But score didn't chage. but I can show toastMessage which "성공" when I run this app
please help me..

1. This is ScoreBroadFragment

   ```
    public class ScoreBoardFragment extends Fragment {

                   GameService mService;
                   boolean mBound = false;
                   private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
                   List<String> listGroup;
                   HashMap<String, List<Score>> listItem;
                   MainAdapter myAdapter;
                   //int correctcount;
                   int brandscore=0;
                   int personscore=0;
                   int capitalscore=0;
                   int proverbscore=0;
                   int teamcount=0;
                   int groupposition=0;
                   TextView groupview;

                   public ScoreBoardFragment() {}

                   public static ScoreBoardFragment newInstance(int teamcount)  {
                       ScoreBoardFragment scoreBoardFragment=new ScoreBoardFragment();
                       Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                       bundle.putInt("teamcount", teamcount);
                       scoreBoardFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                       return scoreBoardFragment;
                   }


                   @Nullable
                   @Override
                   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                       View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scoreboardfragment, container, false);
                       return view;
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                       groupview=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.team_text);
                       expandableListView=(ExpandableListView)view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_listview);
                       listGroup=new ArrayList<>();
                       listItem=new HashMap<>();

                       Bundle bundle=getArguments();
                       teamcount=bundle.getInt("teamcount");
                       initListData();
                       myAdapter=new MainAdapter(getActivity(), listGroup, listItem);
                       expandableListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                   }

                   /*
                   @Subscribe
                   public void correctcountt(ImageFragment.Count event) {
                       GameService
                       correctcount=event.correctcount;
                       initListData();
                   }

                    */

                   @Subscribe
                   public void getPosition(int position)  {
                       groupposition=position;
                       groupview.setText(""+position);
                   }

                   private void initListData() {
                       String[] mystring={"1조", "2조", "3조", "4조", "5조", "6조"};
                       for(int i=0; i<=teamcount; i++) {
                           listGroup.add(mystring[i]);
                       }
                       List<Score> list=new ArrayList<>();
                       list.add(new Score(String.valueOf(brandscore),String.valueOf(capitalscore),String.valueOf(personscore),String.valueOf(proverbscore)));

                       listItem.put(mystring[groupposition], list);
                       //myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }

                   private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

                       @Override
                       public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                                      IBinder service) {
                           // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
                           GameService.LocalBinder binder = (GameService.LocalBinder) service;
                           mService = binder.getService();
                           mBound = true;
                           //Update(mService.getRetriever());
                           //updateScore(mService.notice());

                           updateScore(mService.notice());
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                           mBound = false;
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "실패", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   };

                   private void updateScore(int correct) {
                       brandscore=correct*10;
                       myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }


                   public class MainAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

                       Context mContext;
                       //바깥 데이터(큼직한 데이터)
                       List<String> listGroup;
                       //더 짜잘한 데이터
                       HashMap<String, List<Score>> listItem;

                       public MainAdapter(Context context, List<String> listGroup, HashMap<String, List<Score>> listItem)    {
                           mContext=context;
                           this.listGroup=listGroup;
                           this.listItem=listItem;

                       }
                       @Override
                       public int getGroupCount() {
                           return listGroup.size();
                       }

                       @Override
                       public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
                           //몇번째 큼지막한 덩어리인지 알려준다.
                           return listItem.get(this.listGroup.get(groupPosition)).size();
                       }

                       @Override
                       public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                           return this.listGroup.get(groupPosition);
                       }

                       @Override
                       public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                           return this.listItem.get(this.listGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
                           //해석하면 바깥그룹이 몇번째 인지 얻은다음, 그 안에서 몇번째 item인지를 넣어 구한것이다.
                       }

                       @Override
                       public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
                           return groupPosition;
                       }

                       @Override
                       public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                           return childPosition;
                       }

                       @Override
                       public boolean hasStableIds() {
                           return false;
                       }

                       @Override
                       public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                           String group=(String)getGroup(groupPosition);

                           ParentViewholder parentViewholder;
                           if(convertView==null)   {
                               LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                               convertView=layoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);

                               parentViewholder=new ParentViewholder();
                               parentViewholder.ParentTextView=convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_parent);

                               convertView.setTag(parentViewholder);
                           }

                           else    {
                               parentViewholder= (ParentViewholder) convertView.getTag();
                           }

                           parentViewholder.ParentTextView.setText(group);
                           return convertView;
                       }

                       @Override
                       public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                           //String child=(String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
                           SonViewholder sonViewholder;
                           if(convertView==null)   {
                               sonViewholder=new SonViewholder();
                               LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                               convertView=layoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);

                               sonViewholder.SonTextView=convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_child);
                               convertView.setTag(sonViewholder);
                           }

                           else {
                               sonViewholder = (SonViewholder) convertView.getTag();
                           }
                           Score child= (Score) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
                           sonViewholder.SonTextView.setText(child.toString());

                           return convertView;
                       }

                       @Override
                       public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                           return true;
                       }
                   }

                   public class ParentViewholder   {
                       TextView ParentTextView;
                   }

                   public class SonViewholder  {
                       TextView SonTextView;
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onStart() {
                       super.onStart();
                       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GameService.class);
                       getActivity().bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                       EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onStop() {
                       super.onStop();

                       if(mBound)  {
                           getActivity().unbindService(connection);
                           mBound = false;
                       }
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onDestroyView() {
                       super.onDestroyView();
                       EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
                   }
               }
   ```

2.This is imagefragment

```
                public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {

                        private ImageView myImage;
                        private Button correct;
                        private Button pass;
                        private int resource=0;
                        private int click=0;
                        private int correctcount=0;
                        private TextView correctTextview;

                        public ImageFragment()  {}

                        public static ImageFragment newInstance(int imageresource)  {
                            ImageFragment imageFragment=new ImageFragment();
                            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                            bundle.putInt("imagefile", imageresource);
                            imageFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                            return imageFragment;
                        }

                        private static final Integer[] images = {
                                R.drawable.ajg, R.drawable.brand, R.drawable.ggm, R.drawable.gjt, R.drawable.jkr, R.drawable.kjs, R.drawable.person,
                                R.drawable.sunny, R.drawable.trp
                        };

                        @Nullable
                        @Override
                        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagefragment, container, false);
                            myImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imagefile);
                            pass=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.pass);
                            correct=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.correct);
                            correctTextview=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.correctview);
                            Bundle bundle=getArguments();
                            resource=bundle.getInt("imagefile");
                            myImage.setImageResource(resource);

                            return view;
                        }

                        @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
                        public void changeImage(BrandActivity.ItemClick event)    {

                            switch (event.id)   {
                                case R.id.pass:
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"pass"+click, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    myImage.setImageResource(images[click]);
                                    if(click<images.length) {
                                        click=click+1;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "마지막장입니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case R.id.correct:
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"correct"+click, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    myImage.setImageResource(images[click]);
                                    if(click<images.length) {
                                        click=click+1;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "마지막장입니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    getCorrectcount();
                                    break;
                            }
                            /* if (resource==0) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "시작을 먼저 해주세요!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else    {

                            }
                             */
                        }

                        private void getCorrectcount()   {
                            correctcount=correctcount+1;
                            correctTextview.setText("정답 갯수 : "+correctcount);
                            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), GameService.class);
                            intent.setAction(GameService.ACTION_CORRECT);
                            intent.putExtra("correct",correctcount+2);
                            getActivity().startService(intent);
                            /*
                            Count countevent=new Count(correctcount);
                            EventBus.getDefault().post(countevent);

                             */
                        }

                        /*
                        //eventbus
                        public class Count{
                            int correctcount;
                            public Count(int correctcount)  {
                                this.correctcount=correctcount;
                            }
                        }
                         */

                        @Override
                        public void onStart() {
                            super.onStart();
                            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDestroyView() {
                            super.onDestroyView();
                            EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
                        }
                    }
```

3. This is gameservice

   ```
               public class GameService extends Service {

                   public int correctcount;
                   public static String ACTION_CORRECT="correctt";
                   //게임진행중일 때 계속해서 점수를 Count해주어야 한다.(점수를 제공하는 역할을 할 것)

                   @Override
                   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                       String action=intent.getAction();
                       if(action.equals(ACTION_CORRECT)) {
                           correctcount=intent.getIntExtra("correct",1);
                           notice();
                           /*
                           MediaMetadataRetriever retriever=intent.getParcelableExtra("retriever");
                           update(retriever);
                           이게 불가능하다. 왜냐하면 MediaMetaDataRetriever가 일반 class이기 때문이다.
                           우리가 만약에 만든 Memo class라면 모를까 이미 정의되어 있으므로 바꿀수 x
                            */
                       }
                       return START_STICKY;
                   }

                   public int notice() {
                       return correctcount;
                   }


                   @Nullable
                   @Override
                   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                       return mbinder;
                   }

                   private final IBinder mbinder = new LocalBinder();

                   public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
                       public GameService getService() {

                           return GameService.this;

                       }
                   }


               }
   ```